# disable autosuggest/autocomplete on chrome/safari on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

[autosuggestion/ autocomplete on input box in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE0bs.png)

Hey guys I am trying to turn off the auto-complete/ auto-suggestion that comes on the input box on my website. (The issue is both with Google chrome and Safari).

I want to turn it off for any user who comes to my website i.e. from the code not the settings of the browsers.

I have already tried a variety of things like auto-complete = "off" , auto-complete = "false" , css styling of "display: none" and also jquery hacks like 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName()
x.autocomplete = 'off';

But nothing seems to work here. Can anyone please tell me the solution to the above problem . Also the version of chrome is : 53.0.2785.143
and safari is : 9.1.1 (11601.6.17)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting `autocompletion` values even if the `autocomplete` attribute is set to off.
So try once assigning random string to atrribute.

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

**Since this value is not valid one , the browser must give up.**

Comment: <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="keywords-by" aria-labelledby="label_search_res" id="keywords_input" class="discover-search" placeholder="Start typing to search..." value="" autocomplete="nope">

Comment: Used this in input tag, also tried to change the value of list to off in aria-autocomplete, still doesn't work

Comment: If this is just input box why to use all those stuffs , simply use  '<input type="text" class="discover-search" placeholder="Start typing to search..." autocomplete="nope">'

Comment: Even this doesn't help :(

Comment: did you try autocomplete="nope | off" in <form> tag ?